# Mongodb insert ignore

Tags: mongodb

I've seen an `upsert` used to do the equivalent of an insert ignore. What is the closest thing to doing the following in sql:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES (...)
```

Currently I'm just wrapping things in a `try` block but that seems a bit crude...

```
def insert_obj(obj):
    try:
        res = db.users.insert_one(data)
    except pymongo.errors.DuplicateKeyError:
        res = None
    return res
```

What would be the closest thing for mongo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In a word - nothing. The try-catch on the client is the recommended way.

The only thing to keep in mind is "INSERT IGNORE" was introduced to insert all possible documents from a set when only few violate unique constraints:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO table VALUES (...),(...),(...),(...),(...)
```

In pymongo it is implemented with [insert_many()](https://pymongo.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api/pymongo/collection.html#pymongo.collection.Collection.insert_many)

The method accepts a list of objects to insert and an optional parameter `ordered`, `True` by default. Setting it to `False` will result in similar behaviour as INSERT IGNORE - it will insert all valid documents and reject the duplicates.